# nextpeer always timed out while searching for tournaments

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, request, nextpeer

i am integrating nextpeer for my multiplayer game in unity but   nextpeer always timed out while searching for tournaments.
i am loading my game scene in this method!
WillTournamentStartWithDetails()

Kindly help me !

Comment: Please don't use unity tag got questions related to Unity game engine. There's unity3d tag for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest upgrading to the latest Nextpeer Social SDK and try again.